# How to autocomplete lambdas in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lambda, java-8

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 13 with Java 8 and wonder how to autocomplete lambdas. Before Java 8 I used anonymous inner classes of course. I auto completed by typing "new" and hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>:

[image: autocomplete new]

and choosing the first option.

Now with Java 8 I want to generate lambdas as well, inferring parameters and all, but I can't find autocompletion for it.

Note, this above example is quite easy, but when you have multiple parameters with generic types, e.g. JavaFX Listeners and the like, autocompletion comes in handy.

Comment: Is typing `t->` manually really *that* hard? The fact that you can omit the type of the parameter applies to generic types as well.

Comment: I used an easy example, a more realistic one would be this: `comboBox.focusedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> ...);`

Comment: If you insist on using such long parameter names I see your point. However, I’m wondering why you are using lambda expressions then…

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In Windows or Linux, it’s <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>

In Mac OS, it’s <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Ctrl + Space is enough nowadays

Comment: But it also opens Documentation Popup, it's very annoying!

Comment: Still Ctrl + Shift + Space in Mac OS X, because Ctrl + Space is Spotlight

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 is also Ctrl+Shift+Space.

Comment: On Macos ctr+space shortcut is used by system to change between different input sources (if you have multiple keyboard layouts). Disabling it in Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Input Sources, made Intellij working for me

Answer (score 7):

You can just type `p = s -> f...`, autocompletion will then suggest `false`. If you're not sure about lambda, you can start with the inner class, and then turn it into a lambda expression.

In your example you can press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> afterwards, as follows:

**After completing**:

[image: After completing]

**After pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>**:

[image: After pressing Alt+Enter]

**Result**:

[image: Result]

Clicking the small icon at the gutter shows you the `Predicate.test` method.
[image: Override icon at gutter]

Comment: This is exactly what I do right now, but I have to move the cursor to that grayed out part before I can hit Alt+Enter, right? However, I believe this is too complicated and IDEA should have / does have some other shortcut for that.

Comment: True, I am doing the same. Sorry, I am only aware of these intentions and this little "Override" icon at the gutter, which shows you the overriden Predicate.test method.

Comment: type `p = s -> f...`? is this a joke?