# Auto-generate lambda expression as argument in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, lambda, autocomplete

How do I get IntelliJ to auto-generate a lambda expression as the argument being passed?

[image]

What I want:

[image]

I have seen the Question [*How to autocomplete lambdas in IntelliJ IDEA?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25182285/642706), but that does not seem to produce my desired result.

Comment: Why do you want to have the typecast in your code? It's unnecessary.

Comment: @yole (a) I think your query is irrelevant to the Question, but perhaps I misunderstand.  (b) That was created by IntelliJ after I typed `new Clic` (or some such). IntelliJ 2018.3 offers helpers to convert that piece to various forms. I don't care which form I get, I just don't want to have to type in the listener boilerplate at all. In my first screenshot you can see that IntelliJ knows a `ClickListener` should be passed. I want *some* `ClickListener` to be provided for me. I'll be happy with *any* syntax form of a `ClickListener` implementation that IntelliJ can auto-create.

Comment: Doesn't Ctrl+Shift+Space inside parentheses work for you? For me it suggests `event -> {}` which is pretty close to your desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tagir Valeev already mentioned in his comment, IntelliJ will auto-generate lambda code, but only if your `ClickListener` is a (functional) interface.

E.g.:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface ClickListener {
  void listen();
}

class Clicker {
   void addClickListener(ClickListener listener){
      // ...
   }
}
```

Then, Intellij suggests upon hitting Ctrl+Shift+Space

[image]

Note: As to the `@FunctionalInterface` annotation, [Jav Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html) says

> This annotation is **not** a requirement for the compiler to recognize an interface as a functional interface